# 'Syntax: Unexpected identifier' error when testing via react-scripts-ts

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-scripts

Using react-scripts-ts (2.17.0) I'm trying to setup a test suite. But I'm receiving a "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

[image]

This is the configuration:

**tsconfig.json** ([using the standard of JSX handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#basic-usage))

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

This is a layout of the component:

**./App.tsx**

```js
interface IAppProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  // ...
}

export interface IAppState {
  // ...
}

class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
  // ...
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

And this would be the test setup:

**./app.test.ts**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const app = React.createElement(App);
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(app, div);
});
```

Should I be running Babel somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out styles was loaded as es instead of defined by filetype. Answer found here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14349

Updated from `"react-scripts-ts": "2.17.0"` to `"react-scripts-ts": "^3.1.0"`

Then changed:

```js
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/es/styles/withStyles';
import { WithStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
```

To:

```js
import { withStyles, WithStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
```

And it works.